# Представление строки как числа

Tags: python

Помогите новичку =)

Есть строка, нужно представить её в виде целого числа и сравнить с другим целым числом. При этом преобразование должно нормально работать и в обратную сторону.

**upg:** Мне показалось что правильно сформулировал задачу. Извините, писал в 4 утра.

```
p = random.getrandbits(512)
m = 'hello world... and die'
# преобразовать m в супергигантское число
if m >= p :
    print ('sorry, its overly long message.')
# преобразовать m обратно в исходное состояние
```

Нужно чтобы скрипт выполнился без ошибок

**upg:** К конце концов сделал так.
При условии что исходные символы занимают не более 8 бит каждый (т.е. решение корректно работает с однобайтовыми кодировками) получается число, которое впоследствии можно будет побить по 8 символов и вернуть к исходному виду.

```
import random
p = random.getrandbits(512)
m = 'hello world!...and die'

# 1
ba = [ bin(ord(ch))[2:].zfill(8) for ch in m ]
#print(ba) -> ['01101000' ... '01100101']

# 2
jm = ''
for el in ba:
    jm += el
#print(jm) -> 011010000...110100101100101

# int(jm, 2) -> view in base10
if int(jm, 2) >= p :
    print ('sorry, its overly long message')
else :
    print ('its Ok')
```

Comment: А доки почитать не пробовали? Сам с питоном не сильно знаком, попробовал то, что есть в других языках - помогло. А именно:

    int('1') == 1

Вернет True

Для обработки ошибок (чтобы не было int('1a')) следует почитать:

[Доки питона](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) Первый же пример в "8.3. Handling Exceptions".

Если необходимо для случая '12a3' возвращать 12, то можно каждый символ проверять на "число ли это?" и если да - дописывать к итоговому числу. Если нет - значит возвращать полученное число.

Comment: Ну это уже реально не смешно. На сколько нужно быть ленивым чтобы первую главу любой книги по питону не прочесть. Да что там по питону, по любому языку программирования.
Чем тут писать вопросы по каждому действию, лучше бы прочли 1 рас основы программирования.

Comment: @pilot114 Некогда думать, трясти надо? Успеха!

Comment: Так по какому алгоритму надо преобразовать строку в число? Вариантов куча - кодируете, например, в base64 - вот вам готовое число. Или заменяете каждый символ строки на его код (т.е. пробел, например, на '020' и т.д.) - получилось число...

И зачем преобразовывать обратно? Если можно сохранить исходное, сохранить преобразованное, и в любой момент использовать и то, и другое...

Хотя по задаче - вы случайно не RSA реализуете? Там как раз это и требуется - представить строку в виде набора чисел, над которыми уже совершаем нужные действия. Угадал?

Если угадал, то "Помогите новичку" и сразу RSA?

Comment: Или вам просто длина строки нужна? Если нет, то почему тогда:

    if m >= p :
        print ('sorry, its overly long message.')

Comment: Не RSA, но его тоже надо. Это шифр Шамира, у него криптостойкость понижается, если шифруемое сообщение меньше ключа (как я понял - меньше в битах, но почему-то мне показалось что перевести m в число и сравнить проще, чем представлять m и p в виде битовых последовательностей и сравнивать их длины) Ну может на другом языке бы сделал, в питоне я действительно нуб. Так как это шифрование, хранить открытый текст нельзя, разве что только хэш, чтобы потом проверить правильность дешифровки.

Comment: @pilot114, так Вам надо просто сравнить **длину** ключа и сообщения. Хоть в битах, хоть в байтах - результат не изменится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сложение кодов символов.

```
    >>>temp = 0
    >>>for i in m:
    ...    temp += ord(i)
    >>>print(temp)
```

конкатенация кодов.

```
    >>>temp = ''
    >>>for i in m:
    ...    temp += str(ord(i))
    >>>temp
```

длинна строки

```
    >>>len(m)
```

как очередной вариант.

переводить обратно в строку нет смысла потому, что исходная строка сохранена в m

Comment: Вариант Ortem'а предпологает что строка состоит из цифр, мой-же вариант предпологает что строка состоит из символов.

Comment: @Rom4eg, что Вам все-таки нужно?

Получить 512-битное число, как некий хэш заданной строки?

Какие-то требования к достаточной уникальности этого числа у Вас есть?

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/users/232/avp,
Не понял ваших вопросов. Я ничего не спрашивал.
Мне не нужно, я ответил на вопрос pilot114

Comment: @Rom4eg, извините, перепутал ник. 

Естественно, это вопросы к ТС, т.е.  @pilot114

Answer (score 7):

Если строка состоит только из цифр, то делаем так:

```
>>> a = '345'  
>>> a = int(a)  
>>> print a  
345
```

В обратную сторону:

```
>>> a = str(a)  
>>> print a  
'345'
```

Answer (score 1):

Я так понял нужно преобразовать `Str` в `Int`? тогда так

```
x = "256"  #это строка
y = eval(x) #это уже числовое значение
```

Comment: Никогда, слышите, НИКОГДА не используйте функцию `eval` без веских на то причин! Использование `eval` - это очень серьёзная угроза безопасности программы (особенно если значение, передаваемое в `eval` вводит пользователь). Представьте, что будет, если вместо числа пользователь введёт программу, а `eval` её исполнит.

Comment: да и скорость `eval` наверняка оставляет желать лучшего

Answer (score 1):

В Питон 3 существуют `from_bytes()` и `to_bytes()` методы, которые позволяют интерпретировать строку (последовательность байтов) как целое число:

```
>>> s = "hello".encode()
>>> int.from_bytes(s, 'big')
448378203247
```

И в обратную сторону:

```
>>> n = 448378203247
>>> n.to_bytes((n.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big').decode()
'hello'
```

На более ранних версиях можне преобразование через [`binascii.hexlify()` производить](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7396849/4279).